# Embeding plot into graphicsView in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I use `pyqtgraph` to plot in PyQt5 GUI. I can plot in a pop-up window, but I am trying embed the graph in the `graphicsView` area.

Here is how I can do a simple plot in a new window:

```
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)

    MainWindow.show()
def btn_clk(self):
    L = [1,2,3,4,5]
    pg.plot(L)
```

I tried to use this line to embed the plot, but it doesn't work:

```
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)

    MainWindow.show()
def btn_clk(self):
    L = [1,2,3,4,5]
    self.graphicsView.plot(L)
```

Here is the full code:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(662, 512)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 662, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)

        MainWindow.show()
    def btn_clk(self):
        L = [1,2,3,4,5]
        pg.plot(L)#this line plots in a new window
        self.graphicsView.plot(L)#this line doesn't work



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pg.plot returns an instance of the `pg.graphicsWindows.PlotWindow` class, and this class inherits from `QGraphicsView`, ie `pg.graphicsWindows.PlotWindow` is used to plot but `QGraphicsView` is not. If you want to embed a plot within the Widget you must use the class `pg.PlotWidget()`, you must change:

```
self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
```

to:

```
self.graphicsView = pg.PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

and:

```
def btn_clk(self):
    L = [1,2,3,4,5]
    self.graphicsView.plot(L)#this line doesn't work
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! Works perfectly. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, I just sent you an other email.