# Embed a pyqtgraph plot into a QT .ui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, pyqtgraph

first of all I hope you have me some patience since I'm new on these kind of projects and I also hope not to be asking dumb questions. That being said, my main objective is to create a UI for a raspberry pi 3 which will sense voltage, current, etc from a battery and from a solar panel.

Since I'm working on a raspberry and have some knowledge on Python3, I decided to use QTCreator which as I understand can be translated into python3 through pyqt (https://nikolak.com/pyqt-qt-designer-getting-started/). I installed it on my raspberry pi and made the following UI:

after having a basic UI, I converted the .ui file into .py with the pyuic5 command and I'm able to open the UI with "python3 main.py" and everything seems right:

how the UI looks after opening the main.py file

[image]

Now, I want to have a several plots (like voltage against time, etc) on the UI. I'm using the following for testing:

```
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Scrolling Plots')


p1 = win.addPlot(labels =  {'left':'Voltage', 'bottom':'Time'})
data1 = np.random.normal(size=10)
data2 = np.random.normal(size=10)
curve1 = p1.plot(data1, pen=(3,3))
curve2 = p1.plot(data2, pen=(2,3))
ptr1 = 0

def update1():
    global data1, curve1, data2, ptr1

    data1[:-1] = data1[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
                            # (see also: np.roll)
    data1[-1] = np.random.normal()
    ptr1 += 1

    curve1.setData(data1)
    curve1.setPos(ptr1,0)



    data2[:-1] = data2[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
                            # (see also: np.roll)
    data2[-1] = np.random.normal()
    curve2.setData(data2)
    curve2.setPos(ptr1,0)


def update():
    update1()

timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(2000) # number of seconds (every 1000) for next update



if __name__ == '__main__':
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Is it possible to embbed that plot into my main.py file? If I understood correctly, I'm supposed to use the promoting widget functionality on QTCreator. Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is promoted through Qt Designer is a Widget, ie a class, so it can not be directly promoted, what we must do is place it inside a class as shown below:

**Plotter.py**

```
class  CustomWidget(pg.GraphicsWindow):
    pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
    pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
    ptr1 = 0
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kargs):
        pg.GraphicsWindow.__init__(self, **kargs)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Scrolling Plots')
        p1 = self.addPlot(labels =  {'left':'Voltage', 'bottom':'Time'})
        self.data1 = np.random.normal(size=10)
        self.data2 = np.random.normal(size=10)
        self.curve1 = p1.plot(self.data1, pen=(3,3))
        self.curve2 = p1.plot(self.data2, pen=(2,3))

        timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        timer.start(2000) # number of seconds (every 1000) for next update

    def update(self):
        self.data1[:-1] = self.data1[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
                            # (see also: np.roll)
        self.data1[-1] = np.random.normal()
        self.ptr1 += 1
        self.curve1.setData(self.data1)
        self.curve1.setPos(self.ptr1, 0)
        self.data2[:-1] = self.data2[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
                            # (see also: np.roll)
        self.data2[-1] = np.random.normal()
        self.curve2.setData(self.data2)
        self.curve2.setPos(self.ptr1,0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = CustomWidget()
    w.show()
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Before proceeding I will assume that the files have the following structure:

```
.
├── main.py
└── Plotter.py
```

1. The first thing to do is choose the widget:

[image]

2. Then we right click on this and choose the option to **promote to..**:

[image]

3. In the dialog box we place **CustomWidget** in **Promoted Class Name** and **Plotter.h** in **Header File**, then press the **Add** and **Promote** button.

[image]

4. Then we convert our .ui file to .py

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot eyllanesc, your answer was very useful! I can now embed my plot inside my UI made in QTCreator! I just have a couple of extra doubts hopefully you can help me with:

1) on your 3rd step, you wrote: "In the dialog box we place CustomPlot in Promoted Class Name". If I'm understanding correctly, the name should be CustomWidget, since we are supposed to place the name of the class inside our Plotter.py file, right? (That's what you wrote on the image, maybe you got a little mixed up with the names)

Comment: 2) lastly... I originally wanted to use the GraphicsView widget based on serveral other sites I read, including one on which you also answered (lol, I just noticed your name a couple of minutes ago!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718779/embeding-plot-into-graphicsview-in-pyqt5   I would like to understand what's the difference between his plot and mine, and why did you recommended him to actually use GraphicsView?

Comment: "In Promoted class Name you place the name of the class that makes the graphic, in my example was CustomWidget, and in the Header File you place the name of the file by changing the extension .py to .h – eyllanesc 11 mins ago" <----------------

yeah, I understood that alright :) But on your answer you wrote "place CustomPlot", I think it would be clearer to write "place CustomWidget" in order to follow your example

Comment: cool! That would make it clearer for others in need of a similar answer :) 

I can't send you a chat request because I'm new, is it ok for you if I give you my skype user for a quick chat? I'm from Mexico

Comment: sounds great! Thanks a lot amigo!