# How to embed a PyQtGraph widget into a basic Qt Designer GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyqtgraph

I have been stack with this for days now. Working with PyQt and Qt Designer. Please bear with me since I am new to this.
I am trying to embed a PyQtGraph from Github into a basic GUI created with Qt Designer:

-The graph to embed: https://gist.github.com/cpascual/cdcead6c166e63de2981bc23f5840a98

-The basic Gui (with a button & Graphics view widget) :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 10, 211, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 661, 451))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "aPushButton"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to do it following several tutorials / past questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544446/create-a-widget-to-embed-into-qmainwindow) but i just couldn't achieve it.
Sorry my english is not that good.
Thank you!

Comment: Also see http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/how_to_use.html#embedding-widgets-inside-pyqt-applications

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! actually I tried that. and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872255/embed-a-pyqtgraph-plot-into-a-qt-ui) you suggested. The structure of the Github code was a bit difficult to handle in this situation!

Comment: 1) Do not add external resources such as links as they can break making your question useless, 2) Show what you have tried even if it is unsuccessful and we can help you.